# How to flutter/dart send Image data to apache server php file

Tags: php, apache, flutter, dart, client-server

i want to send image from flutter client to php apache server
but [error null when send data image to middleware (green message is error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz1TL.jpg)

code flutter client : i think body content wrong format

```
 static final String uploadEndPoint =
     'http://192.168.1.4/toothScanr/uploads.php';
 Future<File> file;
 String status = '';
 String base64Image;
 File tmpFile;
 String errMessage = 'Error Uploading Image';

 void upload(String fileName) async {
   http.post(uploadEndPoint, body: {
     "image": base64Image,
     "name": fileName,
   }).then((result) {
     setStatus(result.statusCode == 200 ? result.body : errMessage);
   }).catchError((error) {
     setStatus(error);
   });
   
 }

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Widget showImage() {
     return FutureBuilder<File>(
       future: file,
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
             null != snapshot.data) {
           tmpFile = snapshot.data;
           base64Image = base64Encode(snapshot.data.readAsBytesSync());
           return Flexible(
             child: Image.file(
               snapshot.data,
               fit: BoxFit.fill,
             ),
           );
         } else if (null != snapshot.error) {
           return const Text(
             'Error Picking Image',
             textAlign: TextAlign.center,
           );
         } else {
           return const Text(
             'No Image Selected',
             textAlign: TextAlign.center,
           );
         }
       },
     );
   }
```

code php apache server

restAPI just post to aws server but image file from client not yet error null

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

$target_dir = "/home/ubuntu/picture/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
 $image = $_POST['image'];
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $POST_DATA = base64_encode($image);

       $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/image/test");
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
       $response = curl_exec($curl);
       curl_close ($curl);
       
       echo $response;
?>
```

### why?

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------A

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just passing the `base64image` instead of uploading a file, then you should remove these lines in your PHP script. Stop expecting a `file` to be uploaded to `$_FILES["file"]` in your PHP script.

Since there is nothing uploaded to `$_FILES["file"]`, this explains the error `Undefined index: file in ...`

Since `$_FILES["file"]` is `null` (due to the above error), this explains the error `Trying to access array offset on value of type null ...`

(the "array offset" they are talking about is "name" in `$_FILES["file"]["name"] // <-- This one`).

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

```
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

One more mistake I found in your PHP script:

```
$POST_DATA = base64_encode($image); // <-- this should be base64_decode($image);
```

If you want to upload files to your PHP script, you need to use the `MultipartRequest` class provided by `http` in Flutter. But I recommend using the `dio` library because it provides `FormData` class which will make uploading files + your own data easier.

```
FormData formData = new FormData.from({
   "image": base64Image,
   "name": fileName,
   "file": new UploadFileInfo(file, "something.jpg")
});
response = await dio.post(uploadEndPoint, data: formData);
```